# Pass a custom comparer to a priority queue in Cython

Tags: cython, priority-queue, comparison-operators

The Cython `libcpp` module contains a template for `priority_queue`, which is great, except for one thing: I cannot pass it a custom comparer (or, at least, I don't know how to).

I need this because I need the `priority_queue` to do an `argsort` of sorts rather than a `sort` (yes, a priority queue is optimal for what I want to do), and I need it to be fast.

Is this possible within Cython, perhaps by [wrapping a queue in a custom way](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#simplified-wrapping-with-default-constructor), or not at all?

As an example, say I want to sort a `vector[int[:]]` by one of the elements in a stable way. The actual algorithm is much more complicated.

I decide to sort it by adding it, element-by-element to the `priority_queue`. However, I don't know how to do that.

My actual operation is something like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886178/merging-8-sorted-lists-in-c-which-algorithm-should-i-use), however I'm merging sorted `int[:]`s of 1-D elements by a particular element, where the original lists are also ordered by that element.

I don't mind converting the objects to a buffer/pointer.

Comment: And what do you put into the priority queue? Python-objects? A small code example would make it clearer what you try to achieve.

Comment: It would also be useful to know what you want as a comparator? It wouldn't be too hard if you want to use a `cdef` function (i.e. no bound variables) or a class you're prepared to write in C++. It would be much harder to use a generic Python callable.

Comment: @DavidW It's actually a comparer of 1-D MemoryView objects. Just copies a specific element of both. . And I have no issues writing it as a cdef, although I'd prefer not to go to C++ if possible.

Comment: It's really quite hard to make C++ containers of Python objects (like memoryviews) so this doesn't sound like a good idea unless you already have something that works. However, it's possible that someone else might disagree and have a useful solution.

Comment: @DavidW I don't have anything that works ATM, but I want to get this working. However, I could simply access the data buffer of the `MemoryView`. In any case, I'm using a Cython `MemoryView`, not a Python one... I realize this is still a Python object, but we can do without the `GIL`, etc.

Comment: Using a pointer to the data buffer is fine, except that it doesn't do reference counting, and so you need to make sure that you hold a Python reference to all the memoryviews too (to stop them being freed)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to make this work, but I real don't recommend it. The main problems are:

- C++ containers can't readily hold Python objects (such as memoryviews) unless you're prepared to write reference counting wrapper code (in C++)
- You can get a C pointer to the first element of a memoryview, but:

  - you **must** ensure that a reference to the underlying object (that owns the memory) is kept, otherwise Python will free it and you'll be using accessing invalid memory.
  - a pointer loses all information about how long the array is.
- You're pretty limited as to the comparators you can use (they must be expressable as a `cdef` function) - for example I've written one that compares the second element of the array, but it would require recompiling to change to comparing the third element.

Therefore my advice is to find another way of doing it. However:

You need to write a very small C++ file to `typedef` the type of priority queue you want. This uses `std::function` as the comparator, and I've assumed you want to store `long`s. This file is needed because Cython's template support is pretty limited.

```
// cpp_priority_queue.hpp
#include <functional>
#include <queue>

using intp_std_func_prority_queue = std::priority_queue<long*,std::vector<long*>,std::function<bool(long*,long*)>>;
```

You then can't use the `libcpp.queue.priority_queue` wrapper provided with Cython. Instead, write your own, wrapping the functions you need ("priority_queue_wrap.pyx")

```
# distutils: language = c++

from libcpp cimport bool

cdef extern from "cpp_priority_queue.hpp":
    cdef cppclass intp_std_func_prority_queue:
        intp_std_func_prority_queue(...) # get Cython to accept any arguments and let C++ deal with getting them right
        void push(long*)
        long* top()
        void pop()
        bool empty()

cdef bool compare_2nd_element(long* a, long* b):
    # note - no protection if allocated memory isn't long enough
    return a[1] < b[1]


def example_function(list _input):
    # takes a list of "memoryviewable" objects
    cdef intp_std_func_prority_queue queue = intp_std_func_prority_queue(compare_2nd_element) # cdef function is convertable to function pointer

    cdef long[::1] list_element_mview
    cdef long* queue_element


    for x in _input:
        #print(x)
        list_element_mview = x
        assert list_element_mview.shape[0] >= 2 # check we have enough elements to compare the second one
        queue.push(&list_element_mview[0]) # push a pointer to the first element

    while not queue.empty():
        queue_element = queue.top(); queue.pop()
        print(queue_element[0],queue_element[1]) # print the first two elements (we don't know that we have any more)
```

I've then created an example function that goes through a list of memoryview compatible objects, converts them to pointers, and adds them to the queue. Finally, it goes through the queue in order and prints what it can. Note that **the input list outlives the queue**!

Finally a quick Python test function that creates an appropriate list:

```
import priority_queue_wrap
import numpy as np

a = np.vstack([np.arange(20),np.random.randint(0,10,size=(20,))])
l = [a[:,n].copy() for n in range(a.shape[1]) ]

print(l)
priority_queue_wrap.example_function(l)
```

---

In summary, Python objects + Cython + C++ is a mess: I don't recommend doing it this way (but you can try!)

Comment: Wow, thanks for the incredibly detailed answer. Is there a way to compare an arbitrary element?

Comment: The best I can think of without writing more C++ is to have a global variable `element` and do `a[element] < b[element]` in your comparator function. That's a bit messy though. This is the main limitation of using a `cdef` function - they can't store state

Comment: Could we define a C++ function that returns a lambda or something of the sort?