# A Priority queue with a custom comparator in Cython

Tags: python, c++, arrays, cython, priority-queue

I know there is already [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48475552/pass-a-custom-comparer-to-a-priority-queue-in-cython) question answered but I can't seem to make it work.

I'm currently trying to use a PriorityQueue of pair[double,pair[int,int]] and use the double of the pair (pair.first) to sort itself.
Incase this helps, the method is this one: pathfind(pair[int,int] start, pair[int,int] goal, np.ndarray grid), the 1st and 2nd arguments are passed from a tuple in a normal python method and the grid is just a 2D array.
So... what's the best way to create a PriorityQueue of pair[double,pair[int,int]] in Cython and make it so it compares the first thing in the pair (the double)?

The error it outputs is this: **error C2955: 'cpp_pq': use of alias template requires template argument list**

The cpp_priority_queue.hpp code is this:

```
#include <functional>
#include <queue>
template <class T> //Had to use this since pair wasn't getting imported correctly with <utilities>

using cpp_pq = std::priority_queue<T,std::vector<T>,std::function<bool(T,T)>>;
```

And part of the .pyx code is this:

```
cdef extern from "cpp_priority_queue.hpp":
    cdef cppclass cpp_pq:
        cpp_pq(...) except +
        void push(pair[double,pair[int,int]])
        pair[double,pair[int,int]] top()
        void pop()
        bool empty()

cdef bool compare_element(pair[double,pair[int,int]] a, pair[double,pair[int,int]] b):
    return a.first < b.first

cpdef int pathfind(pair[int,int] start, pair[int,int] goal, np.ndarray grid): # it supposed to output a 
                                                                              # list of tupples, but its 
                                                                              # an int for now until this 
                                                                              # works
    cdef cpp_pq queue = cpp_pq(compare_element)
    cdef pair[double,pair[int,int]] p = (05.7,start) # some random stuff here for testing....
    queue.push(p)
    ##nothing here till this works...
    return 0
```

Comment: Not answering your question, but... Any reason you couldn't just use the `_heapq` module?

Comment: @Amadan, Hi!, I used the builtin heappq in my code when it was pure python and it worked pretty well, but once I started creating large grids or using multiple objects, I noticed it was getting slow, therefore I decided to start using Cython and implement as much as possible in C++ to speed things up, until this issue appeared.

Comment: `heapq` is written in Python. `_heapq` (notice the underscore) is written in C. They have exactly the same API. You should be able to use your old code by simply switching `import heapq` with `import _heapq as heapq`.

Comment: @Amadan Thank you, but... the timing is almost the same using _heap, I'm pretty sure is because of the for loops I've got in the code, which were the primary reason for me to switch to Cython.

Comment: Fair enough....

Comment: Not sure, what you expect: you try use a template class without providing the template argument. So just replace T by the type you use in the typedef.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed the issue, I restarted the project and instead of copying .hpp file I rewrote it and It worked like a charm. 
For some reason at first the utility library was showing errors (red underlined words) so I kept rewriting the code until I managed to break it myself and added the unnecessary template . 
It wasn't until I gave up and restarted everything that It worked.

The final cpp_priority_queue.hpp file is this:

```
#include <functional>
#include <queue>
#include <utility>

using cpp_pq = std::priority_queue<std::pair<double,std::pair<int,int>>,std::vector<std::pair<double,std::pair<int,int>>>,std::function<bool(std::pair<double,std::pair<int,int>>,std::pair<double,std::pair<int,int>>)>>;
```

The .pyx file format is correct, the issue was just with the .hpp file.